# How to re-use repeated HTML in a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I created a main menu for my website (html&css), and it'd be absurd to copy/paste the menu every time I edit it into every single file/page of the website, I need it to appear automatically on every single file.

How can I re-use / include this main menu throughout my website?

I've tried a couple of things with jquery and ajax but it hasn't worked. The last thing I tried was this:

```
function loadDoc() { 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("#").innerHTML = this.responseText; 
        } 
    }; 
    xhttp.open("GET", "my_file_menu.html", true); 
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Examples of what you're doing would be helpful...

Comment: create a snippet and show us what you have

Comment: This was the last code I tried, I don't know how to post it well here on the comments section.

--------------------->






function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("#").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "my_file_menu.html", true);
  xhttp.send();

Comment: @LaloGarcia You should update your question. Not adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can always load a file with AJAX/fetch and use DOM manipulation to add it into the document after loading. But I'm guessing you might want to just use a simple library to do this.

Take a look at [w3.js and the w3.includeHtml() function](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp). It's very simple to use, and doesn't require learning a templating or view framework, e.g. React. Here is an example:

*main-page.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div w3-include-html="main-menu.html"></div> 
    <script>
      w3.includeHTML();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*main-page.html*

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='home'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already did it with ajax.. But instead of dragging the menu html file into every other html file/page, I did an ajax in the menu.html to drag every other page into my "iframe" every time I click on a menu button.

I don't know how to post the code here.